# MSE of an estimator

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, mse

> $R\sim Bi(n,\theta)$
>
> i. The MLE of $\theta$ is $t_1(R) = R/n$. Find the MSE of the estimator
>
> ii. prove that $t_2(R) = R/(n+1)$. Show that the $t_2$ has a lower MSE for $0<\theta<$ $2n+1\over 3n+1$
>
> iii. Explain which estimator is better

I calculated that the MSE of $t_1$ is
$$
\mbox{MSE}(t_1) = Var(R/n)
= \frac{1}{n^2}Var(R)
= \frac{\theta (1-\theta)}{n} .
$$ 
Then
$$
\mbox{MSE}(t_2)=\frac{n\theta (1-\theta)}{(n+1)^2}.
$$

Edit: I think it would be smaller for all values of $\theta$ not just that range

Comment: I can't see why $t_2$ would only be smaller for those values of $\theta$

Comment: Check the definition of the [mean squarred error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Definition_and_basic_properties) and correct your computations.

Comment: @Łukasz Kidziński No, it is not OK. The expression for the second estimator is wrong. The second estimator is biased so there is a term missing.

Comment: So I need to add the square of the bias? The bias being $E($$R\over(n+1)$$)-\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bias of $t_2$ is
$$
\mbox{Bias}(t_2) = E\left (\frac{R}{n+1}\right)-\theta
= \frac{n\theta}{n+1}-\theta
= \theta\left(\frac{n}{n+1}-1\right) .
$$
So
$$
\mbox{MSE}(t_2)
=\frac{n\theta (1-\theta)}{(n+1)^2} +\left\{\theta\left(\frac n{n+1}-1\right)\right\}^2 .
$$
Then
$$
\frac{\theta (1-\theta)}n-\frac{n\theta (1-\theta)}{(n+1)^2} -\left\{\theta\left(\frac n{n+1}-1\right)\right\}^2>0
$$

$$
\frac{\theta(-\theta-3\theta n + 2n+1)}{n(n+1)^2}>0
$$

$$
-\theta-3\theta n + 2n+1>0
$$

$$
\theta<\frac{2n+1}{3n+1}
$$

iii. $t_2$ would be better for all $\theta<\frac{2n+1}{3n+1}$ as it has the lower MSE. Otherwise $t_1$ is better.

Comment: Note that the expression of the bias of $t_2$ can be simplified.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the answer to part iii. is that $t_1$ is better because it isn't biased?

Comment: And what is your conclusion if you compare them on the basis of MSE? What is your interpretation?

Comment: $t_2$ would be better for smaller values of $\theta$ (that satisfy the above inequality)

Comment: Yes. Now that you're done. Would you consider to edit your answer and to provide the full solution to your question (some elements are spread in comments). This will be usefull for others that are interested in your question.

Comment: What if we were just asked which is best? Im trying to see under what condition it would make sense to choose a biased estimator over an unbiased one.